# Adding mashed potatoes for moister/softer cinnamon rolls

Tags: potatoes, rolls

Is it true that adding [mashed potatoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashed_potato) as an ingredient makes [cinnamon sweet rolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_roll) moister and/or softer?

If so, can we simply add a healthy dollop to any yeasted cinnamon roll recipe? Is there any other trick to this?

Could yams or [sweet potatoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_potato) be added instead, for more flavor, with the same benefit of being moister/softer?

Answer (score 5):

Both kinds of potatoes you mention should work as a replacement to a portion of the flour required by the recipe you'd like to follow. I think replacing ~30% of the mass of flour with that mass of your choice of potato is a great start.

The sweet potato might be a better choice because of the added sweetness you'll get. You don't want to go far above 30% if you do that because it will start to dominate the flavor of the roll.

As for softness, it does seem like the end result will be a bit softer although I can't say I've tried it before. You could even consider using some [high quality ricotta](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2010/02/how-to-make-fresh-ricotta-fast-easy-homemade-cheese-the-food-lab-recipe.html) cheese instead of potato. If using ricotta, I'd limit to ~20% replacement for the flour as this is less starchy than the potatoes. This will help to soften the roll as well.